# AutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter margins not working

Tags: android

I'm using an `AutoCompleteTextView` with a custom adapter because I need a custom layout.

Here is the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:clickable="false"
              android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TextView
            ...
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16"
            tools:text="Name"
            />
    <LinearLayout
            ....
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried to use margins in the `TextView` but they do not work. Padding is not a solution because the textview background is clickable and I need the text to be centered vertically.

Any idea why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: is padding working for you ?

Comment: with padding I can sort of achieve what I pretend but this as the drawback of the text not being centered on the textview and the problem with the selected background

Comment: Adding the padding to parent LinearLayout is not an option?

Comment: do you have any design image that you can share here ?

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException No.It isn't

Comment: As @AndroidRuntimeException suggested why can't you give padding for the parent layout ?

Comment: Because I have another constraint. Inside the linearlayout I'm setting other textviews and this "brakes" the layout. The problem is that this should work

Comment: Maybe the full xml could help, another option is change the parent layout by a Relative Layout.